# Wordpress: php strpos not working for WP_Query

Tags: php, wordpress

Ok, so basically I have this code:

```
<?php $query = new WP_Query( array( 'meta_key' => 'usp-custom-1', 'meta_value' => 
get_permalink() ) );

echo $query->found_posts; 
        
if (strpos($query, "0") !== false) {
echo "yes";
} else {
echo "no";
}
?>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is that when the WP_Query output (posts found) is 0, it will say yes, else no.

But it doesn't work.

No matter the number, it always says yes.

I think I'm missing something here.

Not a coder,

need help desperately.

Comment: Hi @robert0, I find this post very helpful for finding where I've gone wrong in small bits of code like this: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just compare with the `$query->found_posts` instead of using `strpos`.

```
<?php 
$query = new WP_Query( 
    array( 
        'meta_key' => 'usp-custom-1', 
        'meta_value' => get_permalink() 
    ) 
);

echo $query->found_posts; 
        
if (0 === $query->found_posts ) {
    echo "yes";
} else {
    echo "no";
}
?>
```